# Why vxlan over udp but not ip

Tags: udp, ip

I am learning VXLAN protocol these days and know that the original payload is encapsulated in a udp header. I wonder why not just encapsulate it in a ip header since the udp header seems useless?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One advantage of a UDP tunnel is with [ECMP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equal-cost_multi-path_routing). VXLAN encodes flow information in the UDP source port thus allowing routers to do flow load balancing.

Note that there are other tunneling protocols such as [NVGRE](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-sridharan-virtualization-nvgre-00) that don't use UDP but go directly on top of IP.

Comment: So packets encapsulation with UDP header is just to support ECMP? and NVGRE prefers smaller packets size to load balancing.

Comment: I don't know if that's the only reason. A similar reason is RSS offload on the NIC. Note that newer hardware can hash the NVGRE key field as well, so this advantage is becoming insignificant.